# CSV import-export in Python

Tags: python, object-oriented, python-2.x, csv

I have finished a really short and small import / export script using Python 2.7, and now I would like to structure it using **classes** and **methods** where possible.

Could anybody give me some advice on what would be the best approach for this?

I haven't used any OOP because I would also like somebody to give me some **best practices** on how this should be done/structured.

```
from similarweb import ContentClient
import csv

FILE_OUT = 'similarweb/new_domains.csv'
FILE_IN = 'similarweb/domains.csv'

content_client = ContentClient("some_key")
final_result = ""

with open(FILE_IN, 'r') as csv_read_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_read_file)
    for i, line in enumerate(reader):
        url = ', '.join(str(e) for e in line)
        final_result += url + " " + (content_client.category(url)['Category']) + "\n"

with open(FILE_OUT, 'w') as csv_write_file:
    csv_write_file.write(final_result)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than going down the OOP route, I would just split this out into a few functions:

```
import csv

from similarweb import ContentClient

CLIENT_KEY = 'some_key'
FILE_IN = 'similarweb/domains.csv'
FILE_OUT = 'similarweb/new_domains.csv'

def extract_data(path, client):
    """Extract the data from the specified path using the client."""
    lines = []
    with open(path) as read_file:
        for line in csv.reader(read_file):
            url = ', '.join(line)  # see note below
            lines.append(' '.join(
                (url, client.category(url)['Category'])
            ))
    return '\n'.join(lines)

def save_data(path, data):
    """Save the data to the specified path."""
    with open(path, 'w') as csv_write_file:
        csv_write_file.write(data)      

if __name__ == '__main__':
    save_data(FILE_OUT, extract_data(FILE_IN, ContentClient(CLIENT_KEY)))
```

Per [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader):

> Each row read from the csv file is returned as a list of strings. No automatic data type conversion is performed.

so there is no need to explicitly convert to strings.

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to accomplish ! Thanks @jonrsharpe for this fast turnaround and the explanations. I have in a csv file some words(each on each line - so one column) and when i export it there will be two columns. I just have one question: is there a way to separate these columns by tabs ?

Comment: @Alexander read the CSV documentation I've already linked to, which explains how to set the delimiter - a comma is the default, but you can specify an alternative if you want.

Comment: I tried before and also now and there's just a simple space. `for line in csv.reader(read_file, delimiter=','):` won't work

Comment: @Alexander I'm not sure what the problem is - I thought you wanted to change the delimiter for the *output file*? You should cut down to a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and take the question to Stack Overflow if you *really* can't get the code to work, but I suggest you spend more time with the documentation and some experimentation first.

Comment: The problem is that I've tried in many ways to do it but didn't succeed

Comment: @Alexander it's pretty difficult to debug from *"won't work"* and *"many different ways"*. Again, if you're really stuck, go to SO (via http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3):

Writing classes is not an aim in itself, it is just a tool. Sometimes it's useful, sometimes it's not. I recommend the talk [*Stop Writing Classes*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0).

Your code looks OK as it is, even if a few things can be improved. For instance, I'm not sure you use the value `i` so you probably don't need `enumerate`.

Comment: you're right, I've changed that. I missed it because I used it at some point. More, I would like to structure my code so that it would be more readable.More, I'd also like to have this done for learning purposes on my own example. I am asking for some OOP for my code because it will probably become bigger and bigger. Would you give it a try with a structure and some explanations along it ?

Comment: @Alexander OOP isn't the only way to structure *"bigger and bigger"*; it's important if you need to **combine state and behaviour**, but otherwise a sensible module of functions would be more flexible.

Comment: That's what I am looking for @jonrsharpe . I was thinking of putting the hole thing in a `class something():` using some `def methods():` and a `main()`. But I don't have any experience and I want to learn the best way of doing it